# iBeacons: Limit to number of ProximityUDID's that can be ranged

Tags: ios8, ibeacon

In Apple AirLocate sample below, there are 3 ProximityUDID's that can be ranged/monitored at a time.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AirLocate/Introduction/Intro.html

Is there  a limit (max #) to how many ProximityUDID's can be ranged/monitored by a device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term is actually **ProximityUUID**.  It is a 64-bit "Universally Unique IDentifier" used for identifying a company, organization, or organizational group's beacons. It is completely different from an iOS device's UDID unique identifier.

**The maximum number** of ProximityUUIDs that can be monitored by a single iOS app **is 20**.